# Non index column in join

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, database-performance

SQL> desc emp_1;

```
Name     Type         Nullable Default Comments 
-------- ------------ -------- ------- -------- 
EMP_ID   NUMBER                                 
EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(20) Y                         
DEPTNO   NUMBER(10)   Y
```

SQL> desc dept

```
Name      Type         Nullable Default Comments 
--------- ------------ -------- ------- -------- 
DEPT_ID   NUMBER       Y                         
DEPT_NAME VARCHAR2(20) Y
```

SQL> CREATE INDEX abc_idex ON emp_1 (deptno);

```
Index created
```

select  /*+ index(emp_1 abc_idex) */ emp_name from emp_1
    INNER JOIN dept ON  emp_1.deptno = dept.dept_id

```
Explain Plan :- 
SELECT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS           271 100000  800000
 MERGE JOIN         271 100000  800000
  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   EXAMINBI    EMP_1   267 100000  500000
   INDEX FULL SCAN  EXAMINBI    ABC_IDEX    131 100000  
  SORT JOIN         4   4   12
   TABLE ACCESS FULL    EXAMINBI    DEPT    3   4   12
```

select /*+ index(emp_1 abc_idex) */ emp_name from emp_1
INNER JOIN dept ON  emp_1.deptno = dept.dept_id
and emp_1.emp_name=dept.dept_name

```
Explain Plan:- 
SELECT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS           272 1   11
 HASH JOIN          272 1   11
  TABLE ACCESS FULL EXAMINBI    DEPT    3   4   24
  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   EXAMINBI    EMP_1   267 100000  500000
   INDEX FULL SCAN  EXAMINBI    ABC_IDEX    131 100000
```

I m clearing my index conncept with your help. My understanding was oracle will skip my index hint as it needs to other column also which is not indexed(emp_name) but still emp_1 table was scanned by index in 2nd case. My question will it help in such case, where I m using another column for join where index is not used(in our example emp_name)? Should we use index hint in such case?
*Note:- I know this is emp_name and dept_name is not logical join but just for testing purpose I created the same.*

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if its recommened to use index hint when in join you
>   are using non index columns from same table. Will it help?

Under most circumstances **No**

Under normal circumstances you simply do not use hints. As you can see here, you've used a hint, Oracle has followed it and done something dumb. You only use hints in very limited circumstances, usually only when you know something about the nature of the data that Oracle can not work out itself. Generally the only hint I use is the cardinality hint, as Oracle can sometimes genuinely not work out the cardinality correctly.

Do not assume that you need to regularly use hints. You don't. Even if a hint works now, it might stop working when the nature of the data changes.

Answer (score 0):

On your case using index probably slows down the whole statement. It is because you are querying the whole table DEPT and EMP_1. Because of hint, Oracle has to query both full tables AND index. Do you really want this?

In simple cases like this I prefere not using hints. Optimizer does its job quite good.

If you use statement for specific department, then the result would be better

```
select emp_name
  from emp_1 INNER JOIN dept ON emp_1.deptno = dept.dept_id
  where dept.dname = 'any department'
```

Comment: I m just learning about the indexes its not for project or anything, just for my understanding purpose. I want to know if its recommened to use index hint when in join you are using non index columns from same table. Will it help? Also, my understanding was in my 2nd query it will be full table scan and will skip my hint. But if you notice explain plan, emp_1 table is accessed by index only and cants see anything about full table scan. Am I missing something in explain plan?

Comment: In 2nd query is scanned your index from hint with full scan. It means Oracle selects all records from index. Index is binary tree structure which stores rowids. For every queried rowid it than select single row from table EMP_1. Full index scan means, that all records are queried, it means that all table rows are queried too.

Answer (score 0):

and so:

```
select /*+ cardinality(0)*/ emp_name 
from emp_1 
   INNER JOIN dept ON emp_1.deptno = dept.dept_id
```